# Calling a jQuery Mobile Popup without a DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, popupwindow

I'm wondering if it's possible to call a jQuery Mobile Popup without a DIV

the normal call is like this :

```
$( "#myPopupDiv" ).popup( "open" );
```

```html
   

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopupDiv">
 <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

Can we do something like that :

```
 $( "<div><p>my popup</p> </div>" ).popup( "open" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a popup dynamically from code.  First create the popup element and append it to the page. Then initialize the popup widget, and call the open method.  In my example below, I am also adding the afterclose callback which destroys and removes the popup after it closes.

```
var pop = '<div id="myDynamicPopup"><p>my popup</p> </div>';        
$("#page1").append(pop);

$("#myDynamicPopup").popup({
    afterclose: function( event, ui ) {
        $("#myDynamicPopup").popup("destroy").remove();
    }
}).popup("open");
```

> Working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x6q7se9s/)**